# loading heavy texts from parse.com crashes app

Tags: android, android-listview, textview, parse-platform, android-volley

I'm making a blog like application, and I'm displaying in listview with image, title and description(2 lines). **I'm NOT facing any issues with images**. **I'm using Volley library for image caching.** The Problem is with texts. Each post has more than 8000 words. Is there any better way to read 'texts' efficiently?

Comment: **What is your problem, exactly? Do you have any code**?

Comment: I have some text contents in Parse.com class. I'm unable to load them efficiently. when I scroll , it keeps on crashing.